# How to change the precision of a math function in oracle

Tags: oracle

How can I change a precision of functions ln and power in oracle? I'm getting very precise results - 40 digits. The problem is that I have a huge table, therefore, the calculations are very long, and I don't need that kind of precision. Standard 7 or 16 digits would be fine, and probably would speed up the computation. Note that I'm not asking about round function because it would only change the format of the result, and would not influence the computation itself.

**Edit**
My real query is complicated, so to keep things simple, let us consider

```
select ln(2) from dual;
```

As a result, I'm getting 
.6931471805599453094172321214581765680782
whereas, I would like to get, e.g., .69314718, but not by rounding the final result .6931471805599453094172321214581765680782. I want to avoid the computation of those additional digits.

Comment: please elaborate your question through sample data and desired outputs.

Comment: There is no setting to change the precision of the function's return value. However, you can try passing in a float datatype rather than a number datatype for a performance gain. See this [AskTom answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=data-types). Be careful though that you aren't [prematurely optimizing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) something that may not be contributing to performance problems.

Comment: Thank you. The performance of ln and power in oracle is so disappointing. I have a create table with parallel 12 clause with query on joined tables with hundreds of millions of records. The select clause is really extensive. The whole create table instruction is done in 1 hour 15 minutes. After I rule out literally two ln operations in the select clause, the instruction is evaluated in couple of minutes. Nothing changes besides the fact that the ln operations are gone.

Comment: Furthermore, I have a create table with parallel 12 clause with query on a single table having relatively small select clause. The whole thing is evaluted in 40 minutes. After I rule out two power operations in the select clause, the evaluation time is reduced to couple of minutes.

Comment: On Monday, when I arrive at my workplace, I'll try to cast the arguments as BINARY_FLOAT.

Comment: Have you tried putting a function-based index on those columns in the select clause?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that on Monday as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the argument conversion to binary_double is the perfect solution for my efficiency problems. For binary_double arguments, power and ln functions produce binary_double results. Now, both of my queries are evaluated in couple of minutes instead of 1 hour 15 minutes and 40 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just trunc the ln to avoid rounding.

```
    select trunc(ln(2),7),ln(2) from dual;
```

Outputs:

```
     0.6931471  0.693147180559945
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that your code will just compute all the digits, and then truncate the result. My problem is on a different level. I have efficiency problem with computing all those digits with the ln function. Therefore, the real task is to force function ln to compute only 7 digits. That's why I don't want to use round or trunc.